# Android Market highlights Return Key SoftKeyboard. How can my App do that?

Tags: android

The Android Market when doing a search, highlights the SoftKeyboard Return Key, hinting to the user the return key will execute the search.

How can my App do the same? eg Highlight the Return Key?

Anyone know?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `EditText`, Set the `imeOptions` property to `actionSearch` or whatever action is appropriate.